# Unable to Resolve Module React Native + Android

Tags: android, react-native

I seem to consistently be getting an error similar to below whenever I reach this specific point when working w/ React Native apps.

[image]

I create an `/App` folder with an `AppContainer.js` file I create a functional component in `app/index.js` (App & app are two different directories) which renders the `AppContainer` component. `app/index.js` looks like this.

```
import React from 'react'
import { AppContainer } from '~/containers'

export default function SnapshelfApp (props) {
    return (
        <AppContainer />
    )
}
```

I export `AppContainer` in `containers/index.js`

```
export AppContainer from './App/AppContainer'
```

It seems like always around this point I get an error saying it's unable to resolve the module and gives me some weird route that doesn't exist.

In iOS I've had this issue and I run `react-native start --reset-cache` and that solves the issue. I tried the same thing w/ Android but still getting the same error.

I'm also using `babel-root-import` but my `babelrc` file is setup fine so I don't see that being the issue.

My project structure is below. The error seems to be skipping over the `/app` directory.

[image]

Any suggestions?